# Custom Post Type duplicating slug for new posts

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

```
// register custom post type forums
function fp_forum_post_type() {
    // set up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Forums',
        'singular_name' => 'Forum',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Forum',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Forum',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Forum',
        'new_item' => 'New Forum',
        'all_items' => 'All Forums',
        'view_item' => 'View Forum',
        'search_items' => 'Search Forums',
        'not_found' =>  'No Forums Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Forums found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Category:',
        'menu_name' => 'Forums',
    );
    //register post type
    register_post_type( 'forums', array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'forums' ),
        )
    );

}
```

For some reason when I create a new post it duplicates the same slug as the first post, so say the slug is forums=hello-world, the next post will automatically be forums=hello-world-2 no matter what the title is...

I have tested on fresh install several times and I get the same issue...

UPDATE: I have discovered that the problem is being caused by my custom metabox:

```
function add_forum_attributes_metabox(){
add_meta_box( 
    'forum_attributes', 
    __('Forum Attributes', 'forumpress'), 
    'forum_attributes', 
    'forums', 
    'side', 
    'high', 
    array( 'id' => 'forum_attributes') 
);
```

}

```
function save_forum_attributes_metabox($post_id, $post){
// Don't wanna save this now, right?

if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;
if ( !isset( $_POST['forum_attributes_nonce'] ) )
    return;
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['forum_attributes_nonce'], 'forumpress/includes/metaboxes/metaboxes.php' ) )
    return;

// We do want to save? Ok!
$key = 'forum_type';
$value = $_POST["forum_type"];
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, FALSE ) ) { // If the custom field already has a value
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
} else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
}
if ( !$value ) delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key ); // Delete if blank

$key = 'forum_category';
$value = $_POST["forum_category"];
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, FALSE ) ) { // If the custom field already has a value
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
} else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
}
if ( !$value ) delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key ); // Delete if blank

$key = 'forum_status';
$value = $_POST["forum_status"];
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, FALSE ) ) { // If the custom field already has a value
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
} else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
}
if ( !$value ) delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key ); // Delete if blank

$key = 'forum_order';
$value = $_POST["forum_order"];
if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, FALSE ) ) { // If the custom field already has a value
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
} else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
    add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
}
if ( !$value ) add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, '0' ); // add 0 if blank
```

}

Comment: So you're creating 2 posts with the same title and expect them to have the same slug?

Comment: No, I'm creating two posts with completely different names and for some reason WordPress is setting the slugs the same as the first one, only adding a 2 on the end...

Comment: And these are the default self assigned slugs? Or are you manually setting slugs? I've never encountered this, this is pure vanilla WordPress core with a default theme and no plugins?

Comment: Yeah WordPress is default setting them itself. Yeah, I'm only running this plugin. I also have two other custom post types set up the same and they work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Silly mistake that I made was using wp_query inside the custom metabox output...

*face palm*

If you found this post googling the same issue, you need to use a different query method as it conflicts with the page.

Using this:

```
$query = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'forums', 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );
```

fixed this problem.